# Extracting the GS1 Company Prefix from a GTIN

Tags: dart, barcode, gs1-ai-syntax

I am trying to get the company prefix from barcodes using dart:

```dart
String extractCompanyPrefix(String gtin) {
  // Ensure the GTIN is a string to handle leading zeros and perform string operations
  String gtinStr = gtin.padLeft(14, '0');

  String prefix = gtinStr.substring(0, 8);
  // remove leading zeros
  prefix = prefix.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'^0+'), '');
  return prefix;
}

void main(List<String> arguments) {
  if (arguments.isEmpty) {
    print('Please provide a barcode.');
    return;
  }

  String barcode = arguments.first;
  String companyPrefix = extractCompanyPrefix(barcode);
  print('Company prefix: $companyPrefix');
}
```

```
❯ dart run dart/company_prefix_checker.dart 8710398527905
Company prefix: 8710398
❯ dart run dart/company_prefix_checker.dart 40111445
Company prefix: 40
```

Is that the correct way and will it result in an accurate GS1 Company Prefix?

---

#### Updated #2 code to add @Terry Burton recommendations:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
import 'lib/application_identifiers.dart';
import 'lib/gcp_length.dart';


Future<String> extractCompanyPrefixFromPrefixList(
    String barcode, Map<String, int> gcpLengths) async {
  if (barcode.length > 12) {
    // remove the leading zeros
    barcode = barcode.replaceFirst(RegExp(r'^0+'), '');
  }else {
    // pad the barcode with leading zeros
    barcode = barcode.padLeft(12, '0');
  }
  // loop through the numbers from 3 to 12 and compare the substring to the GCP list
  for (var i = 3; i <= 12; i++) {
    var prefix = barcode.substring(0, i);
    if (gcpLengths.containsKey(prefix)) {
      print(
          'Found GCP prefix format: $prefix with length: ${gcpLengths[prefix]}');
      return barcode.substring(0, gcpLengths[prefix]!);
    }
  }
  return '';
}

Future<String> extractCompanyPrefix(
    String barcode, Map<String, int> gcpLengths) async {
  var result = await extractCompanyPrefixFromPrefixList(barcode, gcpLengths);
  if (result.isNotEmpty) {
    return result;
  }

  var gai = await GS1ApplicationIdentifier.extract(barcode);
  result = getGCPLength(gai.ai, barcode.substring(gai.ai.length));
  if (result !=
      'There is no matching value. Try GEPIR (https://gepir.gs1.org/) or contact local GS1 MO.') {
    return result;
  }

  return "Invalid Barcode or GCP Not Found";
}

Future<Map<String, int>> loadGcpLengths(String filePath) async {
  try {
    var file = File(filePath);
    var contents = await file.readAsString();
    var jsonData = json.decode(contents);

    Map<String, int> gcpLengths = {};
    for (var entry in jsonData['GCPPrefixFormatList']['entry']) {
      gcpLengths[entry['prefix']] = entry['gcpLength'];
    }

    return gcpLengths;
  } catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Failed to load GCP length data from file: $e');
  }
}

void main(List<String> arguments) async {
  if (arguments.isEmpty) {
    print('Please provide a barcode.');
    return;
  }

  // Specify the path to your local 'gcpprefixformatlist.json' file
  var jsonFilePath =
      path.join(Directory.current.path, 'lib/gcpprefixformatlist.json');

  String barcode = arguments.first;
  try {
    Map<String, int> gcpLengths = await loadGcpLengths(jsonFilePath);
    String companyPrefix = await extractCompanyPrefix(barcode, gcpLengths);
    print('Company prefix: $companyPrefix');
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
```

lib/application_identifiers.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

class GS1ApplicationIdentifier {
  final String ai;
  final String description;
  final String dataTitle;
  final bool fnc1Required;
  final String format;
  final String pattern;

  const GS1ApplicationIdentifier({
    required this.ai,
    required this.description,
    required this.dataTitle,
    required this.fnc1Required,
    required this.format,
    required this.pattern,
  });

  static Future<GS1ApplicationIdentifier> extract(String value) async {
    final applicationIdentifiers = await _loadApplicationIdentifiers();
    for (var ai in applicationIdentifiers) {
      if (value.startsWith(ai.ai)) {
        return ai;
      }
    }
    throw FormatException('Failed to get GS1 Application Identifier from $value.');
  }

  @override
  String toString() {
    return '($ai)';
  }

  static Future<List<GS1ApplicationIdentifier>> _loadApplicationIdentifiers() async {
    // final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('lib/application_identifiers.json');
    final jsonString = await File('lib/_application_identifiers.json').readAsString();
    final List<dynamic> jsonList = json.decode(jsonString);
    return jsonList.map((json) => GS1ApplicationIdentifier.fromJson(json)).toList();
  }

  factory GS1ApplicationIdentifier.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return GS1ApplicationIdentifier(
      ai: json['ai'] as String,
      description: json['description'] as String,
      dataTitle: json['data_title'] as String,
      fnc1Required: json['fnc1_required'] as bool,
      format: json['format'] as String,
      pattern: json['pattern'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

lib/gcp_length.dart:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

final Map<String, String> gs1KeyRegEx = {
  '00': r'^(\d{18})$',
  '01': r'^(\d{14})$',
  '253': r'^(\d{13})([\x21-\x22\x25-\x2F\x30-\x39\x3A-\x3F\x41-\x5A\x5F\x61-\x7A]{0,17})$',
  '255': r'^(\d{13})(\d{0,12})$',
  '401': r'^([\x21-\x22\x25-\x2F\x30-\x39\x3A-\x3F\x41-\x5A\x5F\x61-\x7A]{0,30})$',
  '402': r'^(\d{17})$',
  '414': r'^(\d{13})$',
  '417': r'^(\d{13})$',
  '8003': r'^(\d{14})([\x21-\x22\x25-\x2F\x30-\x39\x3A-\x3F\x41-\x5A\x5F\x61-\x7A]{0,16})$',
  '8004': r'^([\x21-\x22\x25-\x2F\x30-\x39\x3A-\x3F\x41-\x5A\x5F\x61-\x7A]{0,30})$',
  '8006': r'^(\d{14})(\d{2})(\d{2})$',
  '8010': r'^([\x23\x2D\x2F\x30-\x39\x41-\x5A]{0,30})$',
  '8017': r'^(\d{18})$',
  '8018': r'^(\d{18})$',
};

final Map<String, bool> keyStartsWithGCP = {
  '00': false,
  '01': false,
  '253': true,
  '255': true,
  '401': true,
  '402': true,
  '414': true,
  '417': true,
  '8003': false,
  '8004': true,
  '8006': false,
  '8010': true,
  '8017': true,
  '8018': true,
};


List<Map<String, dynamic>> gcpDict = [];

Future<void> fetchGcpData() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.gs1.org/sites/default/files/docs/gcp_length/gcpprefixformatlist.json'));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final allGCPs = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
    gcpDict = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(allGCPs["GCPPrefixFormatList"]["entry"]);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to fetch GCP Length Table data.');
  }
}

String getGCPLength(String aI, String gs1Key) {
  // Check if GS1 Key complies with its corresponding RegEx
  final regex = RegExp(gs1KeyRegEx[aI] ?? '');
  if (!regex.hasMatch(gs1Key)) {
    return 'The GS1 Key has an incorrect length or impermissible characters.';
  }

  String gcpLength = '';
  int j = 12;

  // Normalize input string
  if (keyStartsWithGCP[aI] ?? false) {
    gs1Key = '0' + gs1Key;
  }
  // Determine GCP length
  while (j > 2 && gcpLength.isEmpty) {
    for (var entry in gcpDict) {
      if (entry["prefix"].length == j && gs1Key.startsWith(entry["prefix"])) {
        gcpLength = entry["gcpLength"].toString();
        return gcpLength;
      }
    }
    j -= 1;
  }

  return 'There is no matching value. Try GEPIR (https://gepir.gs1.org/) or contact local GS1 MO.';
}

Future<void> main() async {
  try {
    await fetchGcpData();
    // Example usage
    String gcpLength = getGCPLength('01', '01234567891234');
    print(gcpLength);
  } catch (e) {
    print('Error: $e');
  }
}
```

```bash
❯ dart run company_prefix_checker.dart 8710398527905
Found GCP prefix format: 8710 with length: 7
Company prefix: 8710398
❯ dart run company_prefix_checker.dart 40111445
Found GCP prefix format: 00004 with length: 7
Company prefix: 0000401
```

The code will search https://www.gs1.org/docs/gcp_length/gcpprefixformatlist.json for a match other wise will fallback to regex and AI.

Is that the correct result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that the correct way and results?

No.

The GS1 Company Prefix (GCP) is variable length, between 6 and 12 digits.

The length of the GCP is not specified within the data itself. The length of an instance of a GCP is entirely at the discretion of the licensing GS1 Member Organisation "MO", i.e. the regional issuer of GCPs. Nearly all MOs report their individual allocation scheme to GS1 Global who occasionally publishes a combined mapping of GCP prefixes to overall GCP length.

You cannot separate out the GCP from the remaining data without reference to the prefix length tables that are provided in XML and JSON format, here: https://www.gs1.org/standards/bc-epc-interop

The data is not timely and varies in accuracy with the quality largely depending on the diligence of the GS1 Member Organisation that issued the GCP.

Comment: Thanks @Terry, I updated the code. Is that the correct way?

Comment: Functionally, yes. But walking over potentially all keys of a Map defeats the advantages of the data structure.
Instead, take increasing-length prefixes of the given barcode between 3 and 12 characters and lookup whether it is in the Map, immediately returning the length if so.
This way you are bounded to at most 10 iterations, each of which makes use of Map's fast lookup property, rather than performing up to ~114,000 string comparisons.

Comment: Thanks again @Terry! I updated the code. I noticed some company prefixes are not listed in the prefixes file, for ex, GTIN 07613036665513 has GCP 7613036 but the script is not able to find it. I added some logic to remove the leading zeros for gtin lengths greater than 12. However, if I leave the leading zeros on, then I end up with wrong GCP 0761303 which is not correct.

Comment: From a brief look at the structure, your code does not appear to work either as I specified, nor per your own description. The RegEx isn't a "fallback" and you need to pay attention to not iterate over the Map which make me wonder whether you have understood what it is doing. You have also silently evolved the task from extracting the GCP from a GS1 key to extracting the GS1 key from a fragment of AI formatted data, and therefore become muddled with XY issues. Get one thing working before expanding to a more complex problem. No thoughts on fixing up your code, but others might.

Comment: Thanks @Terry! most of the barcodes I tested results in the correct GCP but with 07613036665513 it could not generate the correct result. Additionally the biip python library also failed to do the same. Can you please test this Gtin with your library and let me know the GCP was correct?

Comment: You provide a fourteen-digit number, but lack any context. Only context (e.g. the AIM Symbology Indicator) will indicate what the scanned message represents. If it is a GTIN-14 then the leading digit will be a packaging level indicator, with the GCP starting at the second digit. Go back to the basic definition: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Trade_Item_Number

Comment: But this question has now crept from a well-defined, tightly-scope activity ("how to extract the GCP from a GS1 key") into "give me what I want given any freeform input", i.e. effectively "please do my homework for me". It is not possible to give reliable advice that will not fail in many cases when the inputs are so open-ended, so it is better not to offer advice at all. I'm out.